# Powershell: how to turn an array of objects into an array of integers?

Tags: arrays, windows, powershell

I create an array of objects that hold the lengths of files with this command:

```
$lengths = dir -File | Sort-Object -Descending | Select-Object Length -First 5
```

However, I want this to be an array of integers, not objects, so I can edit the values easily. How can I convert this $lengths object array into an integer array?

Thank You! :)

Comment: Expand the Property, `Select-Object -Expand Length`. then you can hard type the var if needed, `[int64[]] $lengths = ...`

Comment: Most frequently asked question evar.  Also `| foreach-object propertyname`.

Comment: how can you not change an object's property? Everything in PowerShell is an object, even an integer or a float

Answer (score 4):

The answer was provided in comments but to give it closure, you can expand the values of the objects using [`Select-Object -ExpandProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-9-demonstrate-the-intricacies-of-the-expandproperty-parameter). It's worth noting that your [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.2) statement is not actually sorting by `Length` unless you specify the property *to be sorted*:

```bash
$length = dir -File | Sort-Object Length -Descending | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Length -First 5
```

Personal preference to expand the values, you can use [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2), the syntax is far easier in my opinion but there is no `-First X` here:

```bash
$length = dir -File | ForEach-Object Length | Sort-Object -Descending
```

`$length` type will be `object[]` (object array) even though it will contain an array of [`int64`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.length?view=net-6.0#property-value) values, this is default type for arrays in PowerShell, you can however provide a desired output type either by *type casting* or *hard typing*. Looking into the [Cast Operator `[..]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#cast-operator--) is a good starting point.

```bash
# type casting
$length = [Int64[]] (dir -File | ....)

# hard typing
[Int64[]] $length = dir -File | ....
```

For the latter, `$length` is constrained to be assigned `int64` values or values that can be *type coerced* to `int64`, i.e.:

```bash
[int64[]] $length = 0..10

# can be assigned an `int32` and the array element will be converted to `int64`
$length = 1
$length[0].GetType() # => `int64`

# can be assigned a `string` which contains for example a decimal value
$length = '1.1', 2
# gets converted to int64 (no longer a decimal value)
$length[0] # => 1

# cannot be assigned a `string` which does not contain a type of numeric value
$length = 1, 'hello' # => ...Cannot convert value "hello" to type "System.Int64"...
```

While the former only enforces the type of the array elements however a new array of different type can be assigned:

```bash
$length    = [int64[]] (0..10)
$length[0] = 'hello' # => ...Cannot convert value "hello" to type "System.Int64"...

$length = 'new', 'object', 'array' # succeeds
```

Comment: Nice. Small correction: When no properties are specified, `Sort-Object` tries to use default sort property (in this case `Name`) and if there is no default sort property it compares property by property. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.2#notes

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't use [`Memeber Access Enumeration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.2) for `Length` because it's also a property of the collection (Unlike, for example, `(gci -af).LastwriteTime`). But another way to obtain your desired array is:

```
$Length = (gci -af).Foreach({$_.Length}) | sort -Descending
```

Without casting, $Length is the generic object array:

```
PS > $Length.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]
```

But all its elements are the same type:

```
PS > ($Length | gm).TypeName | select -Unique
System.Int64
```

Comment: Nice call adding on why member access enumeration is not possible in this case